# Method with Onchange decorator used on a checkbox not working properly in edit mode in Odoo 9

Tags: python, odoo

I used Onchange method on a checkbox and set it's behavior to delete a field value upon changing the state of checkbox. The Onchange method triggers on changing the state of checkbox and works fine. But when I edit my form view and save the changes, previously saved data of that field still appears after changing fields data by Onchange method while it should be cleared by Onchange method.
This is the onchange method I used on checkbox to delete the fields value on it's different state:

```
@api.onchange('is_military')
    def onchange_is_military_checked(self):
        if self.is_military:
            self.unit_identificatin_code_id = False
        else:
            self.organization = False
```

It works fine in create state but when I edit the form it also works in edit mode, but when I save the form previous value of that field appears in view, which was set to False (null) by Onchange method in edit mode.

Comment: is `unit_identificatin_code_id` or `organization` fields readonly/invisible by any chance in the form view?

Comment: yes and here is the view code for unit_identificatin_code_id:
`<field name="unit_identificatin_code_id" options="{'no_open':True}" tabindex="7" attrs="{'readonly': ['|', ('from_emp_create', '!=', False), ('is_military', '!=', False)], 'required':[('is_military', '=', False)]}" domain="[('version_ids.state','=','published')]" context="{'search_uic': True, 'fix_view': True, 'tree_view_ref': 'apps_hr.view_apps_unit_identification_code_tree', 'search_view_ref': 'apps_hr.view_unit_identification_code_search', 'uic_code': True}" Placeholder="Enter Unit Identification Code"/>`

Comment: and here is the view code for is_military and organization fields:
` <field name="is_military"/>
                                <field name="organization" attrs="{'readonly': [('unit_identificatin_code_id', '!=', False)], 'required':[('unit_identificatin_code_id','=',False),('is_military','!=',False)]}" placeholder="Enter Working Organization" />`

Answer (score 0):

`@api.onchange` methods work on form view level, whenever a field value is changed in edit mode, `onchange` method of that field is triggered, some other fields value can be changed within that function. But if the fields that is changed in `onachange` method is `readonly/invisible` in form view for example in this case `unit_identificatin_code_id, organization`, saving the form won't actually save the change to that fields. There is a simple workaround in this case, use the property `force_save = 1` on those fields to ensure that even though this fields in form view is `readonly/invisible`, any change on this fields must be saved in the database.

```
<field name="unit_identificatin_code_id" ... ... force_save="1" />
<field name="organization" ... ... force_save="1" />
```

Apparently, this functionality was added in odoo version 11, prior to that version modules are available from OCA to bypass readonly restriction. For odoo version 9 check this [module](https://apps.odoo.com/apps/modules/9.0/web_readonly_bypass/).

Comment: I added `force_save="1"` in my view file and update my module, but still the result is the same as before and nothing changed.

Comment: I checked the update and answer for odoo version and test it, but it did not worked for me.